# Eclipse angular2 plugin file import suggestions

Tags: angular, eclipse-plugin

I am looking possibility for file import suggestion in eclipse Angular 2 plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem comes from typeScript and not from Angular2 Eclipse. The completion for files, directories will be implemented very well for TypeScript 2.1 (or perhaps 2.2).

If you want to play with that:

- install in your project (or other folder) the TypeScript 2.2 with

> npm install typescript@next

- configure TypeScript IDE to use this TypeScript bundle with project properties

> TypeScript / Runtime

See [Configure TypeScript](https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/Configuration#configure-typescript) for more information.

After that completion for files, directories should work:

[image: TypeScript completion for from]

Comment: Please install TypeScript 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT which provides now TypeScript 2.1.4 which supports completion for import path https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/New-and-Noteworthy-1.2.0#typescript-214